# can jQuery get the size of a dynamic element that has not been drawn

Tags: jquery, css

What i mean is if i create a Element with jQuery and DOM

```
var MainHolder = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("box");
```

if i was to call `MainHolder.width()` without drawing the element in the window would it be cleaver and work out that it gets the width from the `.box` CSS class or would it just return 0 as it's not drawn so it can't work it out?

Comment: Could you have not tried it yourself? http://jsfiddle.net/uk3wU/ (the answer is that it returns `0`).

Comment: i was going to but i though i would search SO first and it was not here so i though it would be useful for the answer to be on the site :) SEO and all that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could draw the element, get the width, and undraw it:

```
var MainHolder = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("box").css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: -9999
}).appendTo("body");

var width = MainHolder.width();

MainHolder.css({
    position: "static",
    left: "auto"
}).detach();
```

Comment: Thanks this was the most complete Answer

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery `.width()` you can only get the width of elements in the HTML document.

In my examples below I've set the width in the CSS to `200px`:

[Example without appended to HTML body - returns 0](http://jsfiddle.net/yGbdN/)

[Example when appended to HTML body - returns 200](http://jsfiddle.net/yGbdN/1/)

I believe the main reason for this is that applying `box` to the element and looking for a `.box` rule doesn't work when you have rules such as `.container .box` or `.container2 .box`. jQuery needs to know where this element belongs within your document to understand what width it'll have.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can't fetch the width of an element that is not drawn.

What I have done before is set the top margin of the element to -1000 and the position to absolute, the get the width and height, after that setting the top margin right.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `$.hide()` is better than CSS positioning for this purpose. An element with `left: -9999` could still be visible depending on other CSS styles.

```
$('<div></div>').addClass('box').hide().appendTo('body').width()
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63ypgzvk/)