# Size of an element before it is added to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If we compute the size of an element before adding it to the DOM, the result is wrong, see third line of code here :

```js
var elt = document.createElement('div');
elt.innerHTML = "Blah";
console.log(elt.getBoundingClientRect());  // here : 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, etc.
document.body.appendChild(elt);
console.log(elt.getBoundingClientRect());  // here : 8, 8, 623, 20, 8, 631, 28, 8
```

**How is it possible to compute the size of an element *before* it is added to the DOM ?**

Comment: The size of the element will also depend on the size and styles of its container. An element outside of the DOM has no container, so there is no reliable way to compute its size without adding it to the DOM (at least temporarily).

Comment: possible duplicate of [can jQuery get the size of a dynamic element that has not been drawn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523267/can-jquery-get-the-size-of-a-dynamic-element-that-has-not-been-drawn)

Comment: no @Tudmotu, I don't want to find a jQuery solution. I use plain vanilla JS

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Is there no solution then? I would like the size as if the container is just an empty HTML page with no styling

Comment: @Basj, no solution that I know of, no, apart from adding the element to the DOM (absolutely positioned so the container's overflow styles do not apply, possibly outside of the viewport to avoid visual artefacts) for the duration of the size computation.

Comment: @Basj, I'm pretty sure jQuery is written in javascript... You can do anything that jquery does, in vanilla javascript. So instead of `$(el).append()` you do `el.appendChild`. Not that big a deal. I flagged as dup because the question is conceptually the same, and the answer is basically "no, you can't" for a simple reason - the browser has to do a "reflow" in order to get the boundaries of an element, but anything outside the DOM is ignored, so you have to attach it, which wouldn't always get you the boundaries you expect to get.

Answer (score 1):

Add the element, obtain its bounds, and remove. It won't appear on the screen.

```js
var elt = document.createElement('div');
elt.innerHTML = "Blah";
document.body.appendChild(elt);
var bounds = elt.getBoundingClientRect();  
document.body.removeChild(elt);
document.getElementById("bounds").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(bounds);
```

```html
<div id="bounds">bounds?</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @georg. I tried this already, but the problem is performance. It takes around 1 ms on my machine to do the whole thing. For a project I have, I need to do this on hundreds or thousands of elements... So this will be too slow.

[*Example :* If you click on the top-left logo (sitename) of http://bigpicture.bi/demo,  I have to compute the size of lots of elements before displaying them]

Comment: @Basj: looks interesting, but I don't see why you need to precaclucate element sizes in your code. Maybe you can look for a workaround which wouldn't require that. For example, if the element's position depends on its size, you can place it at arbitrary position first and then make it "float" to the desired place. This is simpler to program and would be quite appealing visually!

Comment: The only reason why I need to precalculate size @georg is that when I want to find the BoundingBox that contains **all** elements of text, then left = element.style.left  (easy)    but for computing "right", I need the element's width

Comment: If you're doing this on hundreds of thousands of elements, performance will become untenable even after the dynamic styling. Because DOM elements have such a large memory footprint, I think you should either explore canvas alternatives, or predetermine element dimensions to make it look organic without the huge overhead of recalculating element dimensions for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because the visual size is dependent on:

1. Rendering the element: if the DOM was rendered after each DOM manipulation, this would lead to massive memory problems.
2. The element's context in the document. How can we work out where an element is in the document if you haven't put it in the document? How can we work out how what styles will be applied to it?

Comment: Let's assume the container of the element is just an empty HTML page with no styling. Is there a solution then ?

Comment: You would have to create a new document and append the element to that to see, but this would be even more performance-intensive and less reliable than simply adding the element to the document in the context it is intended in the first place...

Comment: All tests such as Modernizr etc all append html to the page, run a test and then remove it. The overhead is tiny and until the element is in the DOM it doesn't take up any space. By way of experimentation you could append it to the DOM and make visibility:hidden; so the GFX doesn't render it. Then you should be free to operate on it without it affecting the page