# How to calculate offsetWidth and scrollWidth for option element for select field with multiple attribute in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select input which has multiple attribute. I have given fixed width to the element. Because of fixed width the overflowing content along x-direction is not visible. So I have written a small JavaScript function to set the tooltip using title attribute for the option tags whose offsetWidth is greater than its scrollWidth. This is working very fine in chrome, but in IE 11 the offsetWidth and scrollWidth is always zero. Kindly let me know whether there is another way of calculating the offsetWidth and scrollWidth.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <style type="text/css">
      .selectField {
         width: 100px !important;
      }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function updateTooltip() {
        var element = document.getElementById('selectField');
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
          if (element.options[i].offsetWidth < element.options[i].scrollWidth) {
            element.options[i].title = element.options[i].label;
          }
        }
      }
   </script>
   <body>
      <select multiple class="selectField" id="selectField">
         <option>One Two Three Four Five Six</option>
         <option>One</option>
         <option>Two </option>
         <option>Three</option>
         <option>Four</option>
         <option>Five</option>
         <option>Six</option>
         <option>One Two Three Four Five Six</option>
         <option>One</option>
         <option>Two </option>
         <option>Three</option>
         <option>Four</option>
         <option>Five</option>
         <option>Six</option>
         <option>One Two Three Four Five Six</option>
         <option>One</option>
         <option>Two </option>
         <option>Three</option>
         <option>Four</option>
         <option>Five</option>
         <option>Six</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick="updateTooltip()">Apply Tooltip</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please find the working copy in the below mentioned plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/b9cFuUDXSt4wgcxql3ga?p=preview

Comment: Hope my below solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include jQuery in your project and update the `UpdateTooltip` method to the following. I understood about the creation of dynamic div elements from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523267/can-jquery-get-the-size-of-a-dynamic-element-that-has-not-been-drawn).

```js
function updateTooltip() {
    var element = document.getElementById('selectField');

    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        //Create dynamic div with innertext set to option lable 
        var dynamicDiv = $(document.createElement("div")).text(element.options[i].label).css({
            position: "absolute", left: -9999}).appendTo("body");

        var width = dynamicDiv.width(); //Get width of the div

        if(width + 10 > element.offsetWidth) //Check the width of the div against select element width
            element.options[i].title = element.options[i].label;

        dynamicDiv.css({position: "static",left: "auto"}).detach(); //Remove dynamic div from DOM
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .selectField {
            width: 100px !important;
        }
    </style>

<select multiple class="selectField" id="selectField">
    <option>One Two Three Four Five Six</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two </option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
    <option>Six</option>
    <option>One Two Three Four Five Six</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two </option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
    <option>Six</option>
    <option>One Two Three Four Five Six</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two </option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
    <option>Six</option>
</select>
<button onClick="updateTooltip()">Apply Tooltip</button>
```

Comment: Instead of creating and  destroying the dynamic div inside for loop I did it outside the loop. Other than that it worked fine. Thanks for your answer